# Autofac or the way Delegates work is loading the wrong dependency inside ASP.Net Web API Bot Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, autofac, botframework

Since the Microsoft Bot Framework is using Autofac as a dependency, I figured I'd use it in the rest of my project (using the [Bot Framework project scaffold](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Samples)). I'm trying to load the correct Bot Framework **IDialog** using DI. My *Global.asax.cs* looks like this:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();            

    // Get your HttpConfiguration.
    var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;

    // Register your Web API controllers.
    builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

    // OPTIONAL: Register the Autofac filter provider.
    builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(config);

    builder.RegisterType<EchoDialogState>().Named<IDialog<object>>(ActivityTypes.Message);
    builder.RegisterType<WelcomeDialog1>().Named<IDialog<object>>(ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate);
    builder.RegisterType<UnknownDialog>().Named<IDialog<object>>(string.Empty).PreserveExistingDefaults();

    // Set the dependency resolver to be Autofac.
    var container = builder.Build();
    config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);            
}
```

The *ActivityTypes* are string constants that equate to *message*, *conversationUpdate*, etc. For my controllers, I have a base that looks like this to resolve the Autofac DI Container:

```
public class BaseApiController : ApiController
{
    public IContainer Container { get; private set; } = ((IContainer)((AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver)GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver).Container);
}
```

In my *MessagesController* that catches all bot interactions, my code looks like this:

```
[BotAuthentication]
public class MessagesController : BaseApiController
{

    public virtual async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody] Activity activity)
    {
        using (var scope = Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            var dialog = scope.ResolveNamed<IDialog<object>>(activity.GetActivityType());

            await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => dialog);
        }

        return new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
    }
}
```

The *activity.GetActivityType()* simply returns back a string with equates with the *ActivityTypes* referred to above. When I breakpoint on *scope.ResolveNamed*, it looks like the correct *IDialog* has been returned to *dialog*. However, when the *Conversation.SendAsync* runs, the wrong IDialog is running. For example, I see *EchoDialogState* being injected into *dialog*, but then the code inside *WelcomeDialog1* is always being called instead.

Am I doing this wrong? What would cause the incorrect *IDialog* being run inside the delegate function?

If it helps, this is an example of the IDialog that's running:

```
[Serializable]
public class WelcomeDialog1 : IDialog<object>
{
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }
    public async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
    {
        var message = await argument;
        var name = message.From.Name;

        await context.PostAsync($"Hi {name}. Welcome to SMEBot! First time here stuff.");
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }
}
```

Comment: Was the WelcomeDialog1 called prior to the EchoDialogState? Are u sending a welcome message? If so, are you ending the WelcomeDialog1? Can you show the code for the WelcomeDialog1?

Comment: @EzequielJadib It was yes. That dialog is called when the ActivityTypes.ContactRelationUpdate block is hit. I pasted the code for WelcomeDialog1 in the bottom of my initial question. So I have to end a conversation in order for another one to start? The docs didn't really seem to mention that or I missed it.

Comment: you need to `done` the dialog before you can move on with another dialog. And fyi, `BotFramework` already expose the `Autofac Container` for you to use in `Conversation` class, so you don't need to register a new container, just use `Conversation.Container`.

Comment: @kienct89 Where does the original Autofac Builder.build happen with the Conversation Container? If I want to add special registrations, where do I do that? I'm not seeing anywhere in the bare bones Bot project where this is being done.

Comment: @Rob: the registration is done inside the framework itself, in order to ad special registrations, you need to use something like `var updater = new ContainerBuilder();
var container = Conversation.Container;
updater.Register(); // do your registration
updater.Update(container);`

Comment: @kienct89 Thanks for the information. I probably won't go that route being that [Autofac isn't keen on doing this](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/best-practices/index.html?highlight=update#consider-a-container-as-immutable) and now that I'm reading more [Bot code](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/AlarmBot), they're doing it the way I started to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing a context.Wait in the MessageReceivedAsync method of your WelcomeDialog1,  try doing a context.Done.

In the way you are doing it now, the WelcomeDialog1 is still listening to your messages. Usually the welcome message is done using the ConnectorClient in the MessageController as it is a simple message. You don't need all the dialog infrastructure.

Comment: I changed the code to say `context.Done<string>("Done");`, but it still keeps putting me back into the WelcomeDialog even though I try to pass EchoDialogState back in. Is there better documentation about dialog chains somewhere? The MS site is a little sparse on explaining how all this works?

Comment: The more code I'm reading on the Bot framework suggests that I'm doing this the wrong way. I'm going to redo the project using the [Alarm Bot](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/AlarmBot) as a scaffold. This is a solution to the short term problem but not the best solution for the whole project.

Comment: Don't be discouraged :) There is a bit of ramp up but then things flows smooth. I would recommend going through these task-focused samples. It will help you grasp some of the concepts behind the creation of bots using BotFramework: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples